# simplexml_load_string isn't creating attribute array if XML node is a value node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-deserialization

I am loading an XML string using `simplexml_load_string` and if the node doesn't have any child nodes of it's own then the attributes of that node don't seem to be mapped to the array correctly. Is there any way around this? Please see the `CUSTOM_PROPERTY` sections below:

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<WEBSITE NAME="www.example.co.uk">
    <CATEGORY ID="35702" NAME="CatName" FILE_NAME="" LONG_DESC="" SHORT_DESC="">
        <CUSTOM>
            <CUSTOM_PROPERTY NAME="CATTYPE_INDEX">6</CUSTOM_PROPERTY>
            <CUSTOM_PROPERTY NAME="TEMPLATE_ID">0</CUSTOM_PROPERTY>
            <CUSTOM_PROPERTY NAME="DISPLAY_LIMIT">10</CUSTOM_PROPERTY>
            <CUSTOM_PROPERTY NAME="HIDE_ON_MENU">0</CUSTOM_PROPERTY>
            <CUSTOM_PROPERTY NAME="CAT_COLOUR">#01b2a8</CUSTOM_PROPERTY>
        </CUSTOM>
    </CATEGORY>
```

When I use the following code:

```
$Xml = simplexml_load_string($Str);
print_r($Xml);
```

It returns this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => www.example.co.uk
        )

    [CATEGORY] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 35702
                            [NAME] => CatName
                            [FILE_NAME] => 
                            [LONG_DESC] => 
                            [SHORT_DESC] => 
                        )

                    [CUSTOM] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [CUSTOM_PROPERTY] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 6
                                    [1] => 0
                                    [2] => 10
                                    [3] => 0
                                    [4] => #01b2a8
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
)
```

`CUSTOM_PROPERTY` should have an attribute `NAME` mapped but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attributes are there but are not shown by `print_r()`. Be aware that `print_r()` is not a reliable way of viewing the entire SimpleXML structure.

Example:

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/RzPyZ1Q7)**

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($obj->CATEGORY->CUSTOM->CUSTOM_PROPERTY as $custom_property)
{
  echo $custom_property->attributes()->NAME . "\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
CATTYPE_INDEX
TEMPLATE_ID
DISPLAY_LIMIT
HIDE_ON_MENU
CAT_COLOUR
```

Comment: Oh right, I feel a little silly now (probably should of tried to read the attributes before posting). Many thanks for your time (I will mark as answer in 10 mins).